# ReferenceError: google is not defined on odoo 10

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-api, odoo

I'm trying to use google maps on a view on odoo 10,
it loads the div and an input but gets me an error with the google maps url:

ReferenceError: google is not defined

this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <act_window
            id="action_test"
            name="test"
            res_model="test.mercaderia"
            view_mode="kanban,tree,form,graph,gantt"
        />

        <menuitem
            id="menu_test_mercaderia"
            name="Mercaderias"
            sequence="20"
            action="action_test"
        />

        <menuitem 
            id="menu_all_merc"
            parent="menu_test_mercaderia"
            action="action_test"
            sequence="10"
        />

    <record id="view_form_test" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Mercaderia</field>
        <field name="model">test.mercaderia</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="test mercaderia">
                <header>
                    <button name="do_add_stock" type="object" string="agregar stock" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button name="do_remove_stock" type="object" string="borrar stock" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </header>   

                <sheet>
                    <group name="group_top">
                        <group name="group_left">
                            <field name="nombre"/>
                            <field name="descripcion"/>

                        </group>
                        <group name="group_right">
                            <field name="stock"/>
                            <field name="precio"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
                <notebook>
                    <page string="map">
                          <kanban widget="map">
                              <templates>
                              <t t-name="kanban-box">
                                <input id="csv" name="csv" type="file"/>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhnAOQC2UftAvMhtRLn_TEMjXLiyV9PrQ"></script>

    <script><![CDATA[
            var map;
            function initialize(){

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

                    center: { lat: -2.190874, lng: -79.884467 },
                    zoom: 8,
                });
            }                                   
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                              ]]> 
                          </script>
                          <div id="map" style="width:50%;height:550px;"></div>

                              </t>
                              </templates>
                          </kanban>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

it works fine on the website module, but here gets me the error with the google api

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Google maps you can take reference from module "**base_geolocalize**"

In that module in "**res_partner.py**" model there is method name "**geo_find**" from that you can get idea how to use "Google maps" in your module.

As you told you take reference from website module in that module also where this api is used that model is inherited from "**res_partner**" model which I told you to take reference.

It may be possible you haven't inherited same model ("**res_partner**") and getting error "**ReferenceError: google is not defined**". Inherit res_partner or take reference from **base_geolocalize**.

Comment: can you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917447/in-odoo14-how-to-fetch-google-map-api-key-from-database-and-put-in-script-tag

Answer (score -1):

when you put this line

```
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

google is not loaded you need tell to google to execute initialize in this way

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhnAOQC2UftAvMhtRLn_TEMjXLiyV9PrQ&callback=initialize"></script>
```

the full example will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <act_window
            id="action_test"
            name="test"
            res_model="test.mercaderia"
            view_mode="kanban,tree,form,graph,gantt"
        />

        <menuitem
            id="menu_test_mercaderia"
            name="Mercaderias"
            sequence="20"
            action="action_test"
        />

        <menuitem 
            id="menu_all_merc"
            parent="menu_test_mercaderia"
            action="action_test"
            sequence="10"
        />

    <record id="view_form_test" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Mercaderia</field>
        <field name="model">test.mercaderia</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="test mercaderia">
                <header>
                    <button name="do_add_stock" type="object" string="agregar stock" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button name="do_remove_stock" type="object" string="borrar stock" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </header>   
                <sheet>
                    <group name="group_top">
                        <group name="group_left">
                            <field name="nombre"/>
                            <field name="descripcion"/>

                        </group>
                        <group name="group_right">
                            <field name="stock"/>
                            <field name="precio"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
                <notebook>
                    <page string="map">
                          <kanban widget="map">
                              <templates>
                              <t t-name="kanban-box">
                                <input id="csv" name="csv" type="file"/>    
                                <script><![CDATA[
                                    var map;
                                    function initialize(){
                                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                          center: { lat: -2.190874, lng: -79.884467 },
                                          zoom: 8,
                                        });
                                     }                                   

                                   ]]> 
                                </script>
                                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhnAOQC2UftAvMhtRLn_TEMjXLiyV9PrQ&callback=initialize"></script>
                                <div id="map" style="width:50%;height:550px;"></div>
                              </t>
                              </templates>
                          </kanban>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```